# Function to be used for spectral decompostion of matrix

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra

Can anybody please help in finding out what is best way to do spectral decomposition (or Eigen decomposition) of the matrix. The details of Eigen decomposition can be found in attached link
 1. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matrix_decomposition (refer to section for Eigen decomposition).
2. http://www.real-statistics.com/linear-algebra-matrix-topics/spectral-decomposition/

I looked into attached help link. I see three alternatives as below; Which one of below is closest to spectral decomposition please?
1 SchurDecomposition
2  JordanDecomposition 
3  HessenbergDecomposition

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/MatrixDecompositions.html

Comment: If your matrix is normal, but has inexact entries, `SchurDecomposition[]` will (or can be made to) give the spectral decomposition (in itself, a deep theorem of linear algebra); otherwise, use `Eigensystem[]`, with the caveat that it returns unnormalized eigenvectors.

Comment: Use `Eigensystem` and normalize the eigenvectors.

Comment: The construction is in my answer to the following question:[Why do the eigenvectors for two similar matrixes differ by a large amount](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/75800/why-do-the-eigenvectors-for-two-similar-matrixes-differ-by-a-large-amount) Although the title there is different, it leads to the same question as is asked here, and therefore I would call the current Q a possible duplicate.