# Eigenvectors of numerical matrix

Tags: matrix, linear-algebra

I have a large numerical matrix whose eigenvalues are all distinct. In the documentation for `Eigenvectors` it says:

> For approximate numerical matrices m, the eigenvectors are normalized.
>
> Eigenvectors with numeric eigenvalues are sorted in order of decreasing absolute value of their eigenvalues.

So from what I understand, `Eigenvectors` should give the same result every time. But in reality it gives different results, if I did some heavy calculation tasks in between to evaluations so that the autosaved evaluation results are erased. Why is that?

---

[Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bz-VVgMpZKG4eFFsMUE0VWFRWjQ/view?usp=sharing) is the matrix causing the problem. Simply `Import` it into Mathematica and apply `Eigenvectors`. I'm using "10.0 for Microsoft Windows (32-bit) (June 30, 2014)".

```
omega = Import["Omega.m"]
Eigenvectors[omega]
```

Note that there must be lots of irrelevant calculation in between two evaluations in order to reproduce the problem. Sorry that I can't provide the code that I'm using but I think any heavy calculation will do. Or is there some way to turn off the automatic memoization?

Comment: Can you provide your matrix and the code you use to get the eigenvalues? If not, can you reproduce the problem with an array of random numbers?

Comment: @MarcoB I can provide the matrix and the code but it's kind of long so I'll put it a cloud drive. I haven't been able to reproduce this problem with randomly generated matrices.

Comment: Until your observations have been reproduced, please do not add the [tag:bugs] tag to your question.

Comment: I haven't been able to reproduce the issue. But all the eigenvalues are on the order of 10^33... maybe there is some roundoff causing the order of the eigenvalues to change, which in turn changes the order of the eigenvectors?

Comment: @bills I modified the matrix so that all its elements lie within [-10,10], but the problem is still there. I checked `(omega.#/#)@[First@Eigenvectors@omega]`, and it turned out that it's not constant (with both positive and negative value) so it does seem to be a precision issue. Can I increase the precision without `Rationalize` everything?

Comment: I don't think the quote from the docs implies that eigenvectors have to look the same every time. They are always ambiguous, as seen e.g. [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51776/245). So I don't see any issue here. To get consistent results, just impose a sufficient number of additional conditions on the eigenvectors, such as normalization etc., as I mention in my answer linked above.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a small trick. Let say you don't know the ordering of your eigenvetors.

```
m = RandomReal[1, {10, 10}];
m = m + Transpose[m];
es = Eigensystem[m];
es[[1]]
```

> {9.46387, -2.07941, 1.87017, -1.69204, 1.6247, -1.00992, 0.835742, \
>   -0.786536, 0.669689, -0.463195}

Definitely not ordered. So you can force the order by `Sort`

```
es1 = Transpose[Sort[Transpose[es]]];
es1[[1]]
```

> {-2.07941, -1.69204, -1.00992, -0.786536, -0.463195, 0.669689, \
>   0.835742, 1.6247, 1.87017, 9.46387}

And it will assure the order of the eigenvectors as well.

Now if you get the feeling that the eigenvectors are not normalised, you can force that as well

```
es1 = Transpose[Sort[Transpose[es]/. {x_, y_List} :> {x, Normalize[y]}]];
```

Answer (score 1):

As per comment by @bill, I have not been able to reproduce the problem. I did a trial run using the original matrix using the code below, and the figure values seem fixed. However there are a no. of eigenvectors with low probability of existence (see first figure), and might give rise to problems.

```
ListPlot[Eigenvectors[N[mat]], Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {Style["No.", Large, Bold], 
       Style["Occupation Amplitudes", Large, Bold], 
   Style["", Large, Bold]}, Ticks -> Automatic, 
   LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Large]]
```

[image]

```
ListPlot[Eigenvalues[N[mat]], Frame -> True, Ticks -> Automatic, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Black, Bold, Large]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

To save your results, linking eigenvectors to the right ordered eigenvalues use:

```
omega = Import["Omega.m"]
{evals,evecs}:=Eigensystem[N[omega]]
```

Now the eigenvalues are associated with theire corresponding eigenvectors.
After that I suggest  to make sure youre eigenvectors are orthogonal.
You can do a quick check by:

```
 MatrixForm[Chop[Table[evecs[[i]].evecs[[j]], {i, 1, Length[evecs]}, {j, 1,Length[evecs]}]]
```