# Draw Vectors in Spherical Shell and Then Animate

Tags: plotting, vector, geometry, coordinate-transformation

I want to draw three vectors inside a spherical shell. One of the vectors will be moving, the others will be stationary. However, the animation is the next step. For now, I would like to get the vectors drawn.

The three vectors need to go from the origin to the surface of the sphere. I am using an external program to create a list of angles that change with Temperature and these vectors represent an external magnetic field and easy axis. Those two angles are stationary, one perfectly vertical (along the z-axis) another at phi = pi/4. The third will change, but, can be stationary drawing. Obviously r is constant since they go to the surface.

I tried Show[Graphics3D[Sphere[{0, 0, 0}]], Boxed -> False], but I would prefer something more transparent with axes at the origin not outside the sphere.

Something like this with two more vectors and 3D:

[image]

Comment: Please provide more details. As it is, it's unclear what you really want. Vectors pointing from the origin to the surface of the sphere? Vectors tangent to the sphere? Random vectors or particular ones? Anyway, look at `Graphics3D` and cousins.

Comment: all three vectors from origin to the surface of the sphere

Comment: Please edit your post with the new details (and include more details about how they should be oriented, etc.). Also make sure to read the documentation on `Graphics3D` and `Arrow` in particular. There should be plenty of examples in the documentation of how to do this.

Comment: You may be interested in my answer [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/51778/245) as an example of how to do it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
Manipulate[
 Graphics3D[{{Opacity[0.5], Sphere[]}, 
   {EdgeForm[{Dashed, Red}], 
    FaceForm[None], Cylinder[{{0, 0, -.001}, {0, 0, .001}}]}, 
   {Dashed, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {1, 0, 0}}]}, 
   {Dashed, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 1, 0}}]}, 
   {Dashed, Line[{{0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 1}}]}, 
   Arrow[{{1, 0, 0}, {1.3, 0, 0}}], 
   Arrow[{{0, 1, 0}, {0, 1.3, 0}}], 
   Arrow[{{0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 1.3}}], 
   Text[Style["x", 18], {1.4, 0, 0}], 
   Text[Style["y", 18], {0, 1.4, 0}], 
   Text[Style["z", 18], {0, 0, 1.4}], 
   Text[Style["r", 18, Red], .5 {Cos[θ] Sin[φ], Sin[θ] Sin[φ], Cos[φ]}], 
   {Red, Arrow[{{0, 0, 0}, {Cos[θ] Sin[φ], 
    Sin[θ] Sin[φ], Cos[φ]}}]}}, 
  Boxed -> False], 
  {θ, 0, 2 π}, 
  {{φ, .3}, 0, π}]
```

[image]

Comment: This is the perfect starting point! Thank you! I will work with this and get it setup the way I need before asking anything else.