# Plotting eigenvalues smoothly

Tags: plotting, matrix, linear-algebra, sorting

I am trying to plot how the eigenvalues of a matrix change by changing a given a parameter t. Of course the ordering of the eigenvalues does not matter mathematically but it does when I want to make nice plots.

I know that the eigenvalues will change smoothly as a function of this parameter, is there any way to impose this rule on the way eigenvalues are ordered?

Here is a bit of code that plots the eigenvalues as a function of time (I am sorting the values because otherwise I get a lot of jumps):

```
ham = 1/2*{{0, Ωp, 0}, {Ωp, 
     2 Δp, Ωs}, {0, Ωs, 
     2*(Δp - Δs)}}; 
amp = 100; 
t0 = -120.0; 
dt = 45; 
δ = -999;
δp = -1000.; 
σ = 25.3; 
mat = ham /. {Ωs -> 
    amp*Exp[-(t/σ)^2], Ωp -> 
    amp*Exp[-((t + 
            dt)/σ)^2], Δp -> δp, \
Δs -> δ}
Plot[{(Sort@{Eigenvalues[mat][[2]], 
      Eigenvalues[mat][[3]]})[[1]], (Sort@{Eigenvalues[mat][[2]], 
      Eigenvalues[mat][[3]]})[[2]]}, {t, t0, -t0}, Frame -> True, 
 Axes -> False]
```

What I am trying to fix is shown below. The eigenvalue should change smoothly so at the crossing point the red color should follow all the way down.

[image: The eigenvalue should change smoothly so at the crossing point the red color should follow all the way down.]

Comment: Related: http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/51776/12  In this case I would simply find the intersection point manually and reverse the colouring from there.

Answer (score 7):

A solution (ok, a dirty hack) I found based on the suggestion by Szabolcs is finding the parameter t for which the distance between the two eigenvalues is the smallest by using `NMinimize` and reversing the ordering of the functions. However if there are more than one crossing it would have to be done for each crossing individually...

I am still hoping that there is perhaps a more elegant solution. For now I will post my hack version anyway in case it might help someone in a similar situation.

```
ham = 1/2*{{0, Ωp, 0}, {Ωp, 
     2 Δp, Ωs}, {0, Ωs, 
     2*(Δp - Δs)}}; 
amp = 100; 
t0 = -120.0; 
dt = 45; 
δ = -999;
δp = -1000.; 
δ = 25.3; 
mat = ham /. {Ωs ->amp*Exp[-(t/σ)^2], Ωp ->amp*Exp[-((t + dt)/σ)^2], Δp -> δp,Δs ->δ}
t2 = t /. NMinimize[(Eigenvalues[mat][[2]] - Eigenvalues[mat][[3]])^2, t][[2]]
Show[
Plot[{(Sort[{Eigenvalues[mat][[2]], 
           Eigenvalues[mat][[3]]},Less])[[1]], (Sort[{Eigenvalues[mat][[2]], 
           Eigenvalues[mat][[3]]},Less])[[2]]}, {t, t0, t2}],

Plot[{(Sort[{Eigenvalues[mat][[2]], Eigenvalues[mat][[3]]}, 
      Greater])[[1]], (Sort[{Eigenvalues[mat][[2]], 
       Eigenvalues[mat][[3]]}, Greater])[[2]]}, {t, t2, -t0}]
]
```

Here are the results:

[image]