# Plotting and Animating 3D Vectors

Tags: graphics3d

I'd like to plot 3-D vectors (arrows) on a spherical shell given as in: https://www.google.com.pk/search?q=Bloch+sphere&espv=2&source=lnms&tbm=isch&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwibk5v9k7fQAhXHthoKHUxoCt4Q_AUICCgB&biw=1360&bih=662#imgrc=Z3va-OLlWqIExM%3A

I'd then like to table the different vectors for different times and create an animation of the evolution of the vectors.

How should one go about it?

The expression I essentially wish to plot is:

> $$ \vec{n}(\tau) = \Big ( e^{- \gamma(\tau)} \sin \theta \cos \phi,  e^{- \gamma(\tau)} \sin \theta \sin \phi, \cos \theta \Big ), $$

where $\gamma$ is some function of the time, $\tau$.

Comment: The functions you need to use are `E`, `Sin`, `Cos`. You put your formula inside an `Arrow` statement, inside a `Table` statement that varies time. Use `Graphics3D` to show everything. Put a `Sphere` in the background with low `Opacity`. When it all works, wrap it in an `Animate`.

Comment: Have you seen the [Vector Visualization](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/VectorVisualization.html) guide?

Comment: Have you seen the [Bloch vector animation](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-get-eigenvectors-without-phase-jump/51778#51778) near the end of this post ?