# How to make first component of eigenvectors on grid real and normalize using Map and Normalize?

Tags: matrix, numerics, linear-algebra, grid-layouts

I am trying to use the following approach: [How get eigenvectors without phase jump?](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/51776/how-get-eigenvectors-without-phase-jump)
to apply the same conditions to an array of complex-valued Mathematica eigenvectors.

The matrix solved for is a `3 x 3` matrix. I get my eigenvectors at points on a two-dimensional `N x N` grid, and so my array of eigenvectors has dimensions `N x N x 3 x 3`. The documentation for `Map` allows one to specify `levelspec`, but so far, I have not been able to successfully impose the conditions of normalization and real-first-component to my eigenvectors. I am still having trouble understanding multi-dimensional arrays and indexing. Ideally, I would have an `N x N x 3 x 3` array of eigenvectors whose first component is real, and all eigenvectors normalized. With my limited understanding, I cannot seem to find a way to do this without flattening my array and losing information on the underlying `N x N` grid.

Almost every time, I end up with an array that is flattened (so, `100x100x3` becomes `100`, etc). I tried working with just one eigenvector as in the referenced question, but I really want to preserve the underlying `N x N` structure, as I want to be able to associate each eigenvector to its respective 2D grid's coordinates without losing that information by `Flattening`.

I have attached my code.

```
(* First generate matrix and get eigenvector array. *)
a = 3.19; 
e1 = 1.046; e2 = 2.104; t0 = -0.184; t1 = 0.401; t2 = 0.507; t11 = \
0.218; t12 = 0.338; t22 = 0.057;

h0 = 2*t0*(Cos[2*((1/2)*kx*a)] + 
      2*Cos[((1/2)*kx*a)]*Cos[(ky*a*Sqrt[3]/2)]) + e1;
h1 = -2*Sqrt[3]*t2*Sin[((1/2)*kx*a)]*Sin[(ky*a*Sqrt[3]/2)] + 
   2*1 I*t1*(Sin[2*((1/2)*kx*a)] + 
      Sin[((1/2)*kx*a)]*Cos[(ky*a*Sqrt[3]/2)]);
h1star = -2*Sqrt[3]*t2*Sin[((1/2)*kx*a)]*Sin[(ky*a*Sqrt[3]/2)] - 
   2*1 I*t1*(Sin[2*((1/2)*kx*a)] + 
      Sin[((1/2)*kx*a)]*Cos[(ky*a*Sqrt[3]/2)]);
h2 = 2*t2*(Cos[2*((1/2)*kx*a)] - 
      Cos[((1/2)*kx*a)]*Cos[(ky*a*Sqrt[3]/2)]) + 
   2*Sqrt[3]*1 I*t1*Cos[((1/2)*kx*a)]*Sin[(ky*a*Sqrt[3]/2)];
h2star = 2*
    t2*(Cos[2*((1/2)*kx*a)] - 
      Cos[((1/2)*kx*a)]*Cos[(ky*a*Sqrt[3]/2)]) - 
   2*Sqrt[3]*1 I*t1*Cos[((1/2)*kx*a)]*Sin[(ky*a*Sqrt[3]/2)];
h11 = 2*t11*Cos[2*((1/2)*kx*a)] + (t11 + 3*t22)*Cos[((1/2)*kx*a)]*
    Cos[(ky*a*Sqrt[3]/2)] + e2;
h22 = 2*t22*Cos[2*((1/2)*kx*a)] + (3*t11 + t22)*Cos[((1/2)*kx*a)]*
    Cos[(ky*a*Sqrt[3]/2)] + e2;
h12 = Sqrt[3]*(t22 - t11)*Sin[((1/2)*kx*a)]*Sin[(ky*a*Sqrt[3]/2)] + 
   4*1 I*t12*
    Sin[((1/2)*kx*a)]*(Cos[((1/2)*kx*a)] - Cos[(ky*a*Sqrt[3]/2)]);
h12star = 
  Sqrt[3]*(t22 - t11)*Sin[((1/2)*kx*a)]*Sin[(ky*a*Sqrt[3]/2)] - 
   4*1 I*t12*
    Sin[((1/2)*kx*a)]*(Cos[((1/2)*kx*a)] - Cos[(ky*a*Sqrt[3]/2)]);
H[kx_, ky_] = {{h0, h1, h2}, {h1star, h11, h12}, {h2star, h12star, 
    h22}};

numsquares = 100;
kxs = N[Subdivide[-0.1, 0.1, numsquares]]; kys = 
 N[Subdivide[-0.1, 0.1, numsquares]];
evecs = Table[
   Eigenvectors[H[kxs[[i]], kys[[j]]]], {i, 1, numsquares}, {j, 1, 
    numsquares}];
Dimensions[wfcs]

(* Try to impose condition in several ways. *)
evecs2 = Map[Normalize[#/#[[1]]] &, evecs];
Dimensions[evecs2]

evecs2 = Map[Normalize[#/#[[1]]] &, evecs[[All,All,1]]];
Dimensions[evecs2]
```

Any thoughts? Thanks.

Comment: Tell `Map` to operate on all elements that can be accessed with 3 subscripts, like this:
    `Map[Normalize[#/SelectFirst[#, # != 0 &]] &, evecs, {3}]`
The `SelectFirst` is used to avoid divide-by-zero.

Comment: @LouisB, thanks. If you would like to copy-paste your comment into an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quoting @LouisB's comment:

> Tell `Map` to operate on all elements that can be accessed with 3
> subscripts, like this: `Map[Normalize[#/SelectFirst[#, # != 0 &]] &, evecs, {3}]` The `SelectFirst` is used to avoid divide-by-zero.